# ASP MVC controller action '404 not found' error when decorated with [HttpPost]

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller action method that works when it looks like this:

```
public ActionResult testMethod(int id)
{
    //do something...
    //return something...
    return View();
}
```

But when I specify that it should be a "Post" method, I get a '404 not found error':

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult testMethod(int id)
{
    //do something...
    //return something...
    return View();
}
```

I have other controller action methods in the same controller - both POST and GET, and they work fine. But this one doesn't? What's going on? (I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here...)

Update: 
An ajax call requests the controller method:
    var id = 1;

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/indices/testMethod/',
    data: id,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

I've also tried to test the method with Postman, making sure a POST request is sent.

Update 2: 
I've tried changing the parameter to id, and tried to make sure all method and url locations are capitalised to match, but without any effect.

In Fiddler, I can see that actually a GET request is being made, even though I specify a POST request in the ajax call, so now I need to find out why the request ends up being sent as a GET instead of a POST.

I also tried including an attribute route description, like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("indices/TestMethod/{id:int}")]
    public ActionResult TestMethod(int id)
```

And then tried the ajax call with a different url:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/indices/TestMethod/1',
    data: id,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        var tr = 123;
        var yr = data;
        //Do something
    }
});
```

With attribute routing on, and the paramter value in the URL, I see in Fiddler that first a POST request happens, which gets a 301 status error, but then a GET request is also made, which gets the 404 error.

Update 3: 
After more investigations I narrowed the problem definition down sufficiently that it made sense to open a new question, which can be found here:
[ASP MVC jQuery $.ajax POST request does not call controller method, but works in "fresh" MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893268/asp-mvc-jquery-ajax-post-request-does-not-call-controller-method-but-works-in)

The issue seems to be caused by Content Security Policy settings that were active for this project.

Comment: how do you try to contact this action?

Comment: Are you sure the request is POST'ing to the action, not some other verb? Install Fiddler and examine the request data.

Comment: have added some additional info - as far as I know, a POST request is sent, but it never reaches the controller as I get a 404 error.

Comment: Use Fiddler to see what is actually sent. You may be calling the wrong URL - you are using a url relative to the root, not the current page. If your site is hosted eg in `http://someroot/somesubsite`, your code will call `http://someroot/indices/testMethod/`, not `http://someroot/somesubsite/indices/testMethod`

Comment: You can avoid URL ambiguities by using @Html.ActionLink to generate the target ULR by providing the controller and action names

Comment: are you passing in the param1 parameter since it's required?

Comment: If you change the `type` to `GET` in your last example and use the same URL in jQuery, is the method then called? And have you tried using `$.post` instead of `$.ajax`, just to be sure you aren't missing out any additional configuration?

Comment: When I change the type to GET and use the same URL, the method does get called. Using $.post instead of 4.ajax still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, have you tried with the `FromBody`-attribute for the parameter? Please see my updated answer.

Comment: did you try this data : {id:1};

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `param1` to `id` and see if it works. This may sound stupid but actually I've experienced your problem before myself and that solved the problem.

The other issue I could think of is that in your app, `testMethod`'s path is `/Indices/TestMethod` with uppercase characters. And when you request `/indices/testMethod/` there might be some redirect happening which results in a `GET` request.

Try changing the `url` in your ajax call or try adding a `[Route()]` attribute to set the route name.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Changing the parameters made no difference. What fixed it was using lower-case letters in the url.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add the `FromBody`-attribute to the `int param1`-parameter as it is a simple type? See [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) for more info.

Otherwise a route in the format `/indices/testMethod/{param1}` is expected (i.e. param is required to be in the URL, even if it is a POST-request). This route might not be defined, i.e. in your `global.asax.cs`. You could try making a POST-request to `/indices/testMethod/1` for example. Just to try if it really is a routing issue?

In case you do have issues with your routing, you can define a specific route for your method using [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2). At least for testing/development as this makes it easier to see/understand which route is actually defined for your method.

Some additional questions to narrow down, what it could actually be:

- What format does you `dataGoesHere`-object have?
- What do the POST-methods that work look like? What datatype is their parameter? Reference- or value-type?
- What routes do you register (i.e. in the `global.asax.cs`)?

**Update**

I would try following:

Define controller method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("indices/TestMethod/")]
public ActionResult TestMethod([FromBody] int id)
```

Define action call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/indices/TestMethod/',
    data: id, // alternatively try: {id: id}
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) { }
});
```

Either try passing the `id` as a simple value or try passing it withn an object with an `id`-property (see comment above).

Comment: If this were the case, the parameter would be empty (null if a reference, 0 if an int). The OP can't call the *action* at all. This isn't about a missing parameter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: How do we know with which URL the author is trying the different scenarios he is mentioning? And how do we know, which routes are actually defined? If `param1` is not `UrlParameter.Optional`, then I rekon that the route for the method doesn't match when `/indices/testMethod/` (without further param) is called.

Comment: @PzYon: You answer is right, the [FromBody] is an essential part of the method identification.

Comment: The routing mechanism does not use the request body to recognize the controller method to call, and adding `FromBody` to the parameter declaration may only be required to force one way of binding parameters over the other when it is ambiguous from where the parameter must come. Regardless of whether the parameter is a simple or complex type, it may come from the body without `FromBody`. The attribute would only affect the parameter value observed from the called method, not the ability to locate the method in principle.